# Prevent browser from loading image before attaching element to DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, image

My train of thought was that a browser wouldn't attempt to load a source until it was attached to the DOM, but when I use jQuery to create an image tag, it attempts to load the image source before I attach it. When creating the image tag, does jQuery temporarily attach the element?

In this example, the invalid URL causes a error log in the console, even with the append command commented out ([view in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvPDK/1)).

```
    ​$(document).ready(function() {
    var $img = $("<img>", {
        height:"100px"
        ,width:"100px"
        ,src: "http://content.com/bad.url.jpg"
    });
    //$img.appendTo($("#container"));
});​
```

Comment: I think that's done to facilitate pre-loading, is it a problem for your application?

Comment: Oddly enough, it is, but I can work around it. Just wondering if I missed something.

Comment: Most often when people are working with images they want all pre-loading possible, maybe providing us a wider look at root of the problem may help us help you. `=]`

Comment: I'm developing a content management system, and I wanted to process the content up front, so it's ready to go when I attach upon request. I think I'll switch strategies, and simply process it at request, and then cache the result so it only has to process one time per page. This would also prevent processing pages that are never viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images start loading image files (either live or from cache) once their `src` is set, whether or not they are attached to anything in the DOM.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images