# Javascript : building an image gallery with backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, gallery, image-gallery

I'm building an image gallery using backbone. User can only view one image at a time, when he navigates next/previous using arrow keys he will see next image in the collection.

I have one top level backbone view called gallery view.

```
GalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.collection = PhotosCollection();
    }
});
```

Then for each image I'll create a view

```
PhotoView = Backbone.View.extend
```

I'll keep track of current model in collection that is in view, and I'll create photoView for that model.

My question is regarding pagination, or prefetching images that are not in view. I'm not sure about how galleryView can hold multiple PhotoViews and then show the one that is in focus. I'm thinking about building one long div for entire collection and then adding div's for each photo onto it in the indexed position. What would be the strategy of adding removing new images from that div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I've modified my original code. Though this is obviously untested it should give you a reasonable start. Images start pre-loading as soon as an `img` element has been created and the `src` attribute has been set ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763304/prevent-browser-from-loading-image-before-attaching-element-to-dom#11763417)). They don't have to be attached to the DOM. This revamped version that I've included below will preload images before and after the current image based on the `paginationPadding` variable.

**End Update**

When working with things in Backbone it helps to keep all state related information in your your models and then have the UI respond to it. In this case, you can simply keep track of which image you want to display in a model and then in response to a change in the model tracking what photo you want to view, you can simply re-render the photo gallery to display the desired image. It's reactive.

This is a rough implementation but should hopefully give you some idea of how you might implement a gallery where you can click through the photos like this. Of course, you'd still have a bunch of CSS and such to do. It's incomplete. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
var StateModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    visibleImage: 0
  },

  initialize: function(attributes, options) {
    this.photoCollection = options.photoCollection;
  },

  setIndex: function(photoIndex) {
    if(!this.photoCollection.length) return;

    if(photoIndex < 0) {
      photoIndex = this.photoCollection.length - 1;
    } else if(photoIndex >= this.photoCollection.length) {
      photoIndex = 0;
    }

    this.set('visibleImage', photoIndex);
  },

  setPrev: function() {
    this.setIndex(this.get('visibleImage') - 1);
  },

  setNext: function() {
    this.setIndex(this.get('visibleImage') + 1);
  }
});

var PhotoControls = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.stateModel = options.stateModel;
    this.paginationPadding = options.paginationPadding;
  },

  render: function() {
    var that = this;
    this.$el.empty();

    var ctrlStyle = {cursor: 'pointer', display: 'inline-block', padding: '5px 10px', margin: '0px 5px', border: '1px solid #000'};

    this.$el.append($('<div><< Previous</div>')
      .css(ctrlStyle))
      .click(function() {
        that.stateModel.setNext();
      });

    // Display numbers
    var visibleImage = this.stateModel.get('visibleImage');
    var pgStart = Math.max(visibleImage - this.paginationPadding, 0);
    var pgEnd = Math.min(visibleImage + this.paginationPadding, this.stateModel.photoCollection.length - 1);
    for(var i = pgStart; i <= pgEnd; i++) {
      var $numEl = that.$el.append(
        $('<div>' + (i + 1) + '</div>')
          .css(ctrlStyle)
          .click(function() {
            that.stateModel.setIndex(i);
          });

        if(i == visibleImage) {
          $numEl.css({fontWeight: 'bold', textDecoration: 'underline'});
        }
      );
    }

    this.$el.$('<div>Next >></div>')
      .css(ctrlStyle))
      .click(function() {
        that.stateModel.setPrev();
      });

    return this;
  }
});

var PhotoView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<img src="' + this.model.get('url') + '" />');

    return this;
  }
});

var GalleryView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.paginationPadding = 2;

    this.collection = PhotosCollection();
    this.renderedViews = {};
    this.state = new StateModel(null, {photoCollection: this.collection});
    this.photoControls = new PhotoControls({
      stateModel: this.state,
      paginationPadding: this.paginationPadding
    }).render();
  },

  render: function() {
    if(this.photoView) {
      this.photoView.remove();
    }

    // Pre-fetch images before and after current one based on pagination padding
    var visibleImage = this.stateModel.get('visibleImage');
    var pgStart = Math.max(visibleImage - this.paginationPadding, 0);
    var pgEnd = Math.min(visibleImage + this.paginationPadding, this.stateModel.photoCollection.length - 1);

    for(var i = pgStart; i <= pgEnd; i++) {
      if(!this.renderedViews[fetchModel.cid]) {
        // Images will begin fetching as soon as the 'src' attribute is set on the 'img' element rendered by the view
        this.renderedViews[model.cid] = new PhotoView(this.collection.at(i));
        this.renderedViews[model.cid].render();
      }
      this.$el.html(this.photoView.render().el);
    }

    // Attach the view for the current image
    var renderModel = this.collection.at(this.state.get('visibleImage'));
    if(renderModel && this.renderedViews[renderModel.cid]) {
      this.photoView = this.renderedViews[renderModel.cid];
      this.$el.html(this.photoView.el);
    }

    this.$el.append(this.photoControls.el);

    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't solve the pagination or holding multiple photo views in the gallery view. When you change your state, and remove current photo view, i want to store it somewhere, so that we can go back to it.

Comment: I've just significantly expanded and modified the code to do what you're asking. Check it out! Oh, and it also supports wrapping around at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure about how galleryView can hold multiple PhotoViews and then show the one that is in focus.

This is the easy part. As long as the view isnt attached to the DOM it stays invisible, you can instance as many Views you want and only have one of them attached at any time.

> I'm thinking about building one long div for entire collection and then adding div's for each photo onto it in the indexed position. What would be the strategy of adding removing new images from that div.

Make that an UL with an LI for each picture, anyway, if you want to pre load images, i guess the next one in line is enough, you dont really need to remove the PhotoViews as long as they arent absurd numbers of photos, just scroll them out of view or hide them, if you wish to actually delete views call remove().

Comment: About easy part: if you dont attach that photo view to DOM, how does gallery view keep track of it. I liked your suggestion of not removing photo views, but then wouldn't gallery view div have to be a lot longer in width so that it can store each photo view on it?